# T-SQL Dynamically execute stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a logging function in T-SQl similiar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [logging]    
@PROCEDURE VARCHAR(50),
@MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @MESSAGE

END;
GO
```

I am able to call it like this:

```
execute logging N'procedure_i_am_in', N'log_message';
```

As my stored procedure names are a bit long winded, I want to write an alias or an inline function or so, to call the logging procedure for me, with the current procedure.  Something like this (which is broken):

```
declare @_log varchar(max)
set @_log = 'execute logging N''procedure_i_am_in'', '
execute @_log N'MESSAGE!'
```

And i would put that alias at the top of each procedure.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Not clear on your question.  Do you want help on your code (that you seem to indicate is broken) or do you want opinions on your approach to logging?

Comment: @Russel McClure Question was for help with code, but im receptive to any criticism

Comment: @Chris: your idea is good and I use it, but you can have a genericway to resolve "procedure_i_am_in" as per my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [logging]    
   @PROCID int,,
   @MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX)
-- allows resolution of @PROCID in some circumstances
-- eg nested calls, no direct permission on inner proc
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    -- you are using schemas, right?
    PRINT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@PROCID);
    PRINT @MESSAGE
END;
GO
```

Then

```
execute logging @@PROCID, N'log_message';
```

MSDN on [OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx) and [@@PROCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174408.aspx)

Edit:

Beware of logging into tables during transactions. On rollback, you'll lose the log data

Answer (score 0):

More trouble than it's worth, but
it would be

```
Set @_log = 'exec ....N' + 'MESSAGE!'
Exec (@log)
```

So not a lot of use.

Personally I'sd just rename the SP, or at a push use a tersely named function. Building strings and exec'ing them is an only if you must admin style facility IMHO